# how to determine the current in this circuit

Tags: current

[image]

After calculating total resistance and total current, I am applying current division and I obtain (6/6+6)*1A = 1/2 A. But in the answer key it is presented as 1/3 A.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `(6/6+6)*1A = 1/2 A` -  huh? How? What are these numbers?

Comment: total resistance is 6Ω so total current is 1A. Hence we have 4V voltage drop at 4Ω resistor and 2V voltage drop at 3Ω//6Ω resistors. \$V_{6Ω} = \frac{2V}{6Ω}=\frac{1}{3}A\$

Comment: @EugeneSh. He obviously wanted to write 6/(6+6) = 1/2 which is true... irrelevant but true :P

Comment: Find the voltage across 6 ohms instead.

Comment: Or use the conductances to calculate the current divider: \$(1\ {\rm A})(1/6)/(1/6 + 1/3) = 1/3\ {\rm A}\$.

Comment: Apply a little logic - you know the 1 Amp current will divide between the 3 and 6 Ohm resistors.  Will both resistors carry the same current?

Comment: Current division for 6Ω.  3Ω/(6Ω + 3Ω) × 1A = 1/3A  [Opposite / Sum × Current].

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach to this problem is the following (I will leave the details of the calculations to you): Find the equivalent resistance of the 3 and 6 ohm resistors. Consider that resistance with the 4 ohm resistor as a voltage divider.  That will give you the voltage across the 6 ohms resistor. Ohm's law will then give you the current through the 6 ohm resistor.  If you do these calculations correctly, you will find that the current in the 6 ohm resistor is indeed 1/3 ampere.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be misapplying the concept of current division.  In this circuit, the current through the 4 ohm resistor divides between the 3 ohm and the 6 ohm resistors on its way back to the source.  The current divider formula is

\$ 
I_1 = I \frac{G_1}{G_1+G_2} 
\$

where \$G_1\$ and \$G_2\$ are in this case the *conductances* of the 6 ohm and 3 ohm resistors, respectively, \$I\$ is the total current and \$I_1\$ is the current through  \$G_1\$

You found the total current to be 1A.  Since conductance \$G\$ is the reciprocal of the resistance, \$G = \frac{1}{R}\$, the current in the 6 ohm resistor is

\$ 
I_1 = 1 \cdot  \frac{\frac{1}{6}}{\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{3}}= \frac{1}{3} 
\$